# Meteor - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when start Meteor using windows 10

Tags: javascript, windows, meteor

i have just installed meteor js on windows 10 build 14393.693 but when i run any meteor command (`meteor --version`, `meteor create app` ,`meteor`) it returns this :

```
AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:70
    hasStacks = !!e.stack;
                   ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

i've search in the official forum and in the official github repositry and here but nothing handy

Comment: What's the meteor tool version you are using?

Comment: i've just installed it

Comment: Some meteor version I came across in the past didn't work well on Windows.. you might want to downgrade to 1.3 though I don't know the situation with Windows at the moment.

Comment: the problem is that i have tried it on another windows it worked